# Ubuntu won't start after 15.10 upgrade

Tags: boot, bootloader

I saw there was a similar questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690095/ubuntu-wont-boot-after-upgrade-from-15-04-to-15-10), and I read it, but my situation seems to be different. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 and the following screen appears and the booting stalls there:

[image]
[image]

I tried fixing VMware too with no luck. Any ideas of how to fix this?

P.S I can get a tty.

Comment: Please could you specify whether you can get a tty? and have tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @Riannv  I tried reinstalling ubuntu desktop. Switching to lightdm worked for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that switching over to lightdm  worked. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lighdm`. No idea why.